# ¿Cómo se traduciría al español la palabra "snippet"?

Tags: traducción

En informática, los snippets son pedazos de código rehusable (funciones, métodos, etc). ¿Cuál sería su significado en español?

Comment: Rehusable (rechazable) o reusable (re + usable)?

Comment: Codiguillo?  Codiguito?  Codigo de pegar?

Comment: Hace un tiempo hice la traducción al español de un programa de edición de código ("Html-Kit Tools") y traduje "Snippets" como _Recortes_, pero nunca quedé totalmente satisfecho. Creo que es mejor dejarlo en inglés, todos los programadores saben lo que significa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La mejor traducción que se me ocurre es `fragmento`. Por ejemplo, en un tutorial encontrarías

> Analicemos el siguiente **fragmento** (de código)

*Pedazo*, *trozo* y similares me parece que no encajan tan bien como *fragmento*. El problema es que, a menos que conozcas el contexto, `fragmento` no evoca "código" o "programa" de la misma manera que snippet.

Por supuesto *snippet* podría quedar como otro anglicismo más, y conservar el significado mejor que `fragmento`, pero si tuviese que escoger una palabra, yo escogería `fragmento`.

Comment: En Android, Fragment es una clase bastante usada =\ así que en contextos de desarrollo Android, puede causar confusión pero en otros contextos probablemente está bien

Comment: Me gusta la traducción, +1! Es difícil sin embargo encontrar una palabra justa, pues un snippet es un trozo de código autosuficiente, que puede ejecutarse como tal, mientras que la palabra "fragmento" tiene una connotación algo opuesta.

Comment: +1 *Fragmento de código* es la traducción más habitual, en mi experiencia. Es la que usa Microsoft en [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms165392.aspx), o [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/es_ES/contribute/using/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d1180fba3730-7eb2CS5.html), o [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPG9M/DDX/DDX/UserGuide/usingcodesnippetsbestpractices.html?lang=es)...