# ¿Existe una traducción de "exploit" al español en el ámbito de la seguridad informática?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, informática

En [la pregunta de ayer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19582/12637) sobre cómo traducir "sanitize", se presentó una tira cómica titulada "Exploits of a mom". Esa tira cómica tiene una traducción al español que se tituló "Exploits de una madre". Lo que me hace pensar que la palabra "exploit" aplicada en el ámbito de la seguridad informática no tiene traducción o adaptación actualmente.

[Según el Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exploit), "exploit" como sustantivo significa "hazaña, acto heroico" (no me lo esperaba, la verdad), y como verbo significa "hacer uso productivo de algo" (como en "explotar los recursos naturales") o bien "hacer un uso injusto de algo para tu propio beneficio" (como en "explotar a los trabajadores").

La acepción de "exploit" como sustantivo aplicada a la seguridad informática tendría más que ver con esta última acepción del original como verbo, ya que un "exploit" es, [según la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit), un fragmento de código que aprovecha una vulnerabilidad de un sistema para obligarlo a comportarse de forma no deseada.

Visto que la propia Wikipedia en español tiene una entrada para "exploit", se me hace complicado pensar que pueda haber una traducción, pero aún así lanzo la pregunta: ¿cuál podría ser una buena traducción para "exploit" en español?

Comment: Mmmmm me encanta esta pregunta. Como referencia añadida, tenemos la definición de la etiqueta [exploit](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/exploit/info) en [so]: _An exploit is a piece of software, a chunk of data, or sequence of commands that takes advantage of a bug, glitch, or vulnerability in order to cause unintended or unanticipated behavior to occur. This frequently includes such things as gaining control of a computer system, allowing privilege escalation, or a denial of service attack._

Comment: A mí [explotar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HKDxVB1) me parece bastante apropiado en cuanto a _Utilizar abusivamente en provecho propio el trabajo o las cualidades de otra persona_, cambiando persona por algo más genérico.

Comment: Claro, pero _explotar_ es un verbo, y _explotación_ me suena raro, por no decír _explotío_. :D

Comment: Miré [explotación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HKCKFQ5) y me di cuenta que la única acepción que conocía es la 2ª (_Conjunto de elementos dedicados a una industria o granjería_), mientras que la 1ª (_Acción y efecto de explotar_1._) seguramente es lo que buscamos. Mmmm

Comment: ¿No sería "puerta trasera"? Aunque suene un poco peliculero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Abusar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0EUOgTV)" puede ser un sinónimo de "explotar" con las connotaciones negativas de hacer un mal uso.

> Hacer uso excesivo, injusto o indebido de algo o de alguien

En informática esa *explotación* sería un *abuso* (uso indebido) de una vulnerabilidad. Yo en el ámbito de la seguridad lo traduciría sin embargo como "explotar" (*explotar* una vulnerabilidad).

Ahora, el juego de palabras de "exploits of a mum" de la tira cómica lo veo intraducible (propondría "abusos de una madre", pero se podría malinterpretado fácilmente. La segunda acepción de *abusar* se refiere al "*trato deshonesto a una persona de menor experiencia*").

En cualquier caso, creo que mi respuesta a la pregunta sería "no", ya que "exploit" como dice el [link a wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit) que aportas puede ser tanto un fragmento de código (un [*snippet*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13573/5481)) como un ataque mediante ingeniería social (un discurso o un argumento). Al primero me referiría como una `vulnerabilidad` (y usaría "aprovechar" o "explotar" como verbos para "hacer uso o saco ventaja de esa vulnerabilidad") mientras que al segundo como un "engaño" o "ataque". El primero es un nombre y el segundo una acción (verbo) con lo cual no creo que puedan coincidir en el término usado, a diferencia de como ocurre en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

¿Que tal **ardid, artificio o explotar**?

Un *exploit* es un método para romper un programa o acceder ilegalmente a ordenadores, aprovechando un fallo de seguridad -una vulnerabilidad- existente en un determinado protocolo de comunicaciones, sistema operativo, o herramienta informática.

Explotamos un fallo, empleamos un ardid o un artificio para entrar en una red.